# How can I get and print/log the currently installed exact version number of Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, version, echo, lumen

As I mentioned in the Q-title, I want to print/log the currently installed version of Lumen framework i.e. the exact version number of Lumen thro' Bash script in GitBash terminal or PHP snippet in any Model / Controller.

I recently upgraded Lumen by providing `"laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0",` in composer.json and running `composer update` then.

And I know we can get the correct version number in Laravel by either `php artisan --version` or `App::VERSION();` in terminal or code respectively.

How can I do the same with Lumen, as I ain't so familiar with Lumen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application` class of Lumen has a public method called `version()`.

[You can see it in the repo here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/9.x/src/Application.php#L163)

So I'd say it's quite the same as you would do in Laravel.